# vue-flatpicker - can't get selected date on close event

Tags: events, datepicker, vuejs2, flatpickr, vue-events

When I listen to flatpicker's on-close event and log v-model's value in the event function I get previously selected date

```
<flat-pickr v-model="myObject.happened_at" @on-close="onDateChange"></flat-pickr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found a solution for this problem. You have to listen on @input event

```
<flat-pickr v-model="myObject.happened_at" @input="onDateChange"></flat-pickr>
```

As I understand @on-change event is triggered before the v-model is updated so you get previous date instead of selected one.

Comment: Great, it worked for me too! Can you accept this as answer?